# operator overloading as a friend function

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I create a template class and want to overload an operator + (several times). I do this in the following way

```
template <typename T> class Polynomial;

template <typename T>
const Polynomial<T> operator +(const Polynomial<T>& poly, const T& scalar);

....

template <typename T>
class Polynomial {
    ....

    public:

    ....

    Polynomial operator +(const Polynomial& other) const {
       // impelementation
    }

    friend const Polynomial<T> operator + <> (const Polynomial<T>& poly, const T& scalar);

};

template <typename T>
const Polynomial<T> operator +(const Polynomial<T>& poly, const T& scalar) {
    // implementation
}
```

However, I got the following error (which corresponds to the line that begins with 'friend')

```
problem2.cpp:282:45: error: declaration of ‘operator+’ as non-function
problem2.cpp:282:45: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
problem2.cpp:282:47: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
```

Following Raxvan's advise, I've changed  the code

template  class Polynomial;

```
template <typename T>
const Polynomial<T> operator +(const Polynomial<T>& poly, const T& scalar);

template <typename T>
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Polynomial<T>& other);

....

template <typename T>
class Polynomial {
    ....

    public:

    ....

    friend ostream& operator << <> (ostream& out, const Polynomial<T>& other);

    Polynomial operator +(const Polynomial& other) const {
       // impelementation
    }

    template <typename NOT_T>
    friend const Polynomial<NOT_T> operator +(const Polynomial<NOT_T>& poly, const NOT_T& scalar);

};

template <typename T>
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Polynomial<T>& other) {
    // implementation
}

template <typename T>
const Polynomial<T> operator +(const Polynomial<T>& poly, const T& scalar) {
    // implementation
}
```

And in this code I don't have problems with operator << as I had with operator +. Can anyone explain the defference?

Comment: What's with the angle-brackets? `friend const Polynomial<T> operator + **<>** (`, lose them...

Comment: they are needed since it's template function

Comment: Updated the answer; the operator << you used is very much the same as a function it just doesn't have a name it's operator <<

Answer (score 2):

The problem is subtle.  Your syntax is very close to being
correct.  I think your friend declaration should be:

```
friend Polynominal<T> const operator+<T>( ... );
```

but both VC++ and g++ accept:

```
friend Polynominal<> const operator+<T>( ... );
```

when they can see the declaration:

```
template <typename T>
const Polynomial<T> operator+(const Polynomial<T>& poly, const T& scalar);
```

(I can't find anything in the standard to justify this off hand,
but since both VC++ and g++ do it, I suppose that it's something
I've missed.)

And therein lies the problems.  The declaration at namespace
scope of `operator+` is hidden by the in-class definition.  The
compiler complains because the `operator+` it finds (the in
class definition) isn't a template itself (although it is
a member of a class template).

If you don't have the problem with `operator<<`, it's because
you don't have a member function with the same name.

There are several ways of solving this problem.  The simplest is
probably to make all of the `operator+` friends.  Or not: the
most common approach to this is to implement `operator+` in
terms of `operator+=` (which should be a member, in all cases).
In which case, `operator+` doesn't have to be a friend.
Or you don't make `operator+` a template at all, but definite it
inside your class template:

```
template <typename T>
class Polynomial
{
    friend Polynomial operator+( Polynomial const& lhs, Polynomial const& rhs )
    {
        //  ...
    }
    friend Polynomial operator+( Polynomial const& lhs, T const& rhs )
    {
        //  ...
    }
    friend Polynomial operator+( T const& lhs, Polynomial const& rhs )
    {
        //  ...
    }
}
```

(Note that the functions being defined are *not* templates, but
separate overloaded non-template functions, one for each
instantiation of `Polynomial`.  But the results end up being the
same.)

In this case, you probably would want to have a member function,
called by the `operator+` functions, which would do the actual
work; you don't want too much code directly inline like this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the same definition when you label a function as friend, this includes the template used above with another type , not T

```
template <typename T> class Polynomial;

template <typename T>
const Polynomial<T> operator +(const Polynomial<T>& poly, const T& scalar);

template <typename T>
class Polynomial {
public:

    template < class NOT_T> //must respect the deffinition from above
    friend const Polynomial<NOT_T> operator + (const Polynomial<NOT_T>& poly, const NOT_T& scalar);

};

template <typename T>
const Polynomial<T> operator +(const Polynomial<T>& poly, const T& scalar)
{
    //...
}
```

Edit:

For a simplified explanation i have changed the function to `foo` and `bar` to illustrate the difference in declarations:

```
template <typename T> class Polynomial;

template <typename T>
void bar(const Polynomial<T>& );

void foo(const Polynomial<float> & );//foo for speciffic float

template <typename T>
class Polynomial {
public:
    template <typename> //this is also valid declaration; 
    friend void bar(const Polynomial<T> & );
    //it just has to have template because it's a template functions declaration

    //not a valid declaration:
    //friend void bar <> (const Polynomial<T> & );

    //this declaration has no template;
    //it refers to a foo function specific to Polynomial<T> type
    //so if you use Polynomial<float> there must be a foo for floats
    friend void foo(const Polynomial<T> &);
};

template <class T>
void bar(const Polynomial<T>&)
{
}

void foo(const Polynomial<float> &)
{
}

void main()
{
    Polynomial<float>   pf;
    Polynomial<int>     pi;

    foo(pi);//error since there is not **foo** declared for int 
    foo(pf);//ok; we have **foo** for  Polynomial<float>

    bar(pf);
    bar(pi);//both ok since bar is templated function;
}
```

Raxvan.

Comment: thanks, that worked! However, I don't understand why. Can you explain it by answering the modified question?

Comment: but in my case both functions are template (they have template arguments)

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator+` is a function template, to make this a friend, you need to declare it fully including the template parameters, however with a *different* template parameter, for example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class Polynomial;

template <typename T>
const Polynomial<T> operator +(const Polynomial<T>& poly, const T& scalar);

template <typename T>
class Polynomial {
    public:

    Polynomial operator +(const Polynomial& other) const {
      std::cout << "inline +" << std::endl;
    }

    // Here introduce a different type to indicate that this is a template...
    template <typename U>
    friend const Polynomial<U> operator + (const Polynomial<U>& poly, const U& scalar);

};

template <typename T>
const Polynomial<T> operator +(const Polynomial<T>& poly, const T& scalar) {
    std::cout << "friend +" << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
  Polynomial<int> f;

  f = f + 1;

  f = f + 1.; // this fails

  f = f + Polynomial<int>();
}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked! However, I don't understand why. Can you explain it by answering the modified question?

Comment: However, this would make every possible `operator+` (for every possible `U`) a friend of `Polynomial<T>`, whereas only the `operator+` for `T` needs to be a friend. Though I agree that this  probably isn't a problem for his case in practice.

Comment: According to [this site](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Ffriends_and_templates.htm) you would need `friend const Polynomial<T> operator+<T>(const Polynomial<T>&, const T&);` to make only the specific `T` version a friend of `Polynomial<T>`. This is similar to the OP's first try, but with an additional `T` inside the `<>` after the function name.

Comment: This is wrong.  This makes _all_ instantiations of the template `operator+` friends of _all_ of the instantiations of `Polynomial`, which is not (I think) what is wanted.

Comment: @JamesKanze, see I wasn't sure about this either, but, I can't think of what the downside of this is? May be you can expand your answer to indicate what the downsides are...

Comment: @Nim As you have written it, `Polynomial<double> operator+(Polynomial<double> const& poly, double const& scaler)` is a friend of `Polynomial<int>`.  It's not necessarily a big problem (since you are the author of both), but it does expose more than what was originally asked for.